# Value Error: 'embedded null character' when attempting to write decompressed data to a file

Tags: python, compression, zlib

The `decompression` is successful, however when I attempt to write it to the disk I get a `ValueError` as follows:

> error: embedded null character.

I'm using `python3`, with `zlib`.

```
data.seek(offset, 0)
x = zlib.decompress(data.read(compSize))
with open(fName,"wb+") as d:
    d.write(x)
```

How can I write the raw `binary` data?

It is simple to do in `C`. I don't exactly understand why does `python` try to `interpret` the `bytes` in it.

Comment: Where did `fName` come from?  I suspect that's what actually contains the null character, not the data you're trying to write to the file.  (The *complete* traceback would have made it clear as to where the problem was.)

Comment: Perfect tip! Solved my issue :D greatly appreciated!